# is the mapper class from com.datastax.driver.mapping threadsafe?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

it would seem so since it receives a Session object(which is thread-safe), but i could find no "official" statement on the subject

can anyone please confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapper is indeed thread-safe as are the rest of the components in the driver.  All members are either final or volatile with exception to the cached preparedQueries that is always updated in a synchronized block.  Is there a particular concern that you have?